# Handling 'The EJB does not exist' or 'Cannot load from BACKUPSTORE FOR Key'

Tags: java, jsf, exception, jakarta-ee, ejb

so the problem is pretty simple:

We are using JSF 2.0 with Primefaces and EJB to handle our application and we have encountered a problem. We have a single `@SessionScoped` bean in which we store all ours `@Stateful Session Beans`.

In one case, (when we didn't handle some exceptions from JPA) and there is an exception:

```
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.2.0.v20110202-r8913): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "webuser_idwebuser_pk"
  Detail: Key (idwebuser)=(6) already exists.
```

It leads to destruction of one of our `@Stateful Session Bean`.
So after refreshing the website, when JSF is still working correctly, after filling the form and trying to submit it, by invoking a method from that Bean there is an exception:

```
javax.ejb.NoSuchObjectLocalException: The EJB does not exist. session-key: 22900a4d007e1f-6dcc714a-0
```

What is the most problematic, we have to restart and redeploy the application to make it work on the same computer (or web browser) because the JSF's `@SessionScoped` Bean is somehow kept through cookies or something.

So the solution I guess would be to force the destuction of that `@SessionScoped` or refresh the session somehow, but actually I have no idea how to do so.
Or what would be a better approach.

Thanks!

Comment: I think I had a similar issue here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10948631/must-close-browser-to-get-authentication-data-in-postconstruct-method (sorry, got no answers). Which is your setup?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To remedy this, you need to be aware about the difference between application- and system exceptions in EJB.

Those roughly correspond to checked and runtime exceptions respectively.

Application exceptions are supposed to be handled by your own code, and will not cause a transaction rollback or the destruction of a bean. System exceptions have the opposite effect and will cause a rollback and the destruction of the EJB bean.

The latter effect is what you are seeing. JPA throws unchecked exceptions, which thus become system exceptions, which thus cause your SFSB to be destroyed. JSF nor CDI managed beans participate in this "system exception" thing, so they will just propagate the exception and will stay alive.

What you probably want is to define a new Exception that you annotate with @ApplicationException and then set its rollback attribute to true. Catch the JPA exception within your SFSB  and wrap and rethrow it with your custom exception.

Answer (score -3):

Ok so I've found the answer on my own.
Actually what I've needed was to handle exceptions in JSF view by extending ActionListenerImpl.

The original article is here:
[Original](http://www.jroller.com/mert/entry/jsf_handling_exceptions_by_extending)

But what I've done was to extend the exception handling with invalidating the HTTP session which, in the end, ended the life of `@SessionScoped` Managed Bean and leaded to reinjection of SSBs. Like this:

```
private void gotoErrorPage(MethodExpression expression) {
        FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        Application application = context.getApplication();

        HttpSession session = (HttpSession) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getSession(false);
        if (session != null) {
            session.invalidate();
        }

        NavigationHandler navHandler = application.getNavigationHandler();
        navHandler.handleNavigation(context, null == expression ? null : expression.getExpressionString(), NAV_ERRORPAGE);
        context.renderResponse();
    }
```

Comment: Invalidating the HTTP session for every little JPA exception  is a **really** bad solution. This will be a massive overhead and causes every view to expire for no good reason.

Comment: we handle other exceptions but this handles the one we didn't predict.

Comment: If you do a "catch all" (catch Exception, or even Throwable if you're really desperate), then there won't be any unpredicted exceptions. The JPA ones are all documented (see their respective JavaDocs) so can hardly be called unexpected/unpredictable. But hey, it's your code! Just warning others not to follow your solution blindly ;)

Comment: Why is this blind. We do not have every statement surrounded with try/catch so I think it's really good solution to avoid system failure and lack of session beans.

Comment: I didn't say "this" is blind, but that users should not follow it blindly. If you really think it's a really good solution, then I'm sorry. I don't mean to offend you or anyone, but the fact you're not seeing it indicates a problem in your understanding or general insight. At best your solution is a quick hack to be set in place for a short time. At worst it's a desperate fallgrind since you failed to grasp the root cause. At no point is it a "really good solution". Sorry...

Comment: Why do you think I feel offended. I am just curious what is the better way to handle the exceptions which users can encounter in long term using of the application, since it is usually not possible to predict every single exception.
And since some of this exceptions may affect the EJB beans to be cooked we need to invalidate the user's session. So how should we handle this ?
And I am just a little curious since the solution you gave is not really clear and indicates that you can predict every single situation.

Comment: Invalidating the HTTP session is not the right solution for this problem. Although there were times, when I needed a  hammer but it wasn't accessible, so I used a screwdriver instead.